# Why create a object using its base object as its type but creating it with a specific type object

Tags: oop

My question is hard to translate to English so I will do my best.

Reading I about Liskov Substitution Principle(LSP) I found this example that is very common to shows the what LSP is important.

Having a `AreaCalculator` class, a `Shape` class, and a `Rectangle` class the code shows the problem calling AreaCalculator when a newrectangle is created as its based class but using and a child type like this `Rectangle newRectangle = new Square()`.

My question is why I would like to create an object using its base class as its type if I can use the specific type? What is the benefits

```
Rectangle newRectangle = new Square(); vs  `Square newRectangle = new Square();`
```

This method return a wrong area since square

```
public void TwentyFor4X5RectangleFromSquare()
        {
            Rectangle newRectangle = new Square();
            newRectangle.Width = 4;
            newRectangle.Height = 5;
            Assert.AreEqual(20, AreaCalculator.CalculateArea(newRectangle));
        }



 public class AreaCalculator
    {
        public static int CalculateArea(Rectangle r)
        {
            return r.Height * r.Width;
        }

        public static int CalculateArea(Square s)
        {
            return s.Height * s.Height;
        }
    }

public class Rectangle
{
    public virtual int Height { get; set; }
    public virtual int Width { get; set; }
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    private int _height;
    private int _width;

    public override int Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set
        {
            _width = value;
            _height = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set
        {
            _width = value;
            _height = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much, much easier to refactor. Enforces you to use what you need and not make ad-hoc implementations, giving you better code. Allows not knowing what is the actual type, only the base type (very useful for methods arguments)

Comment: @amit do you know any documentation that I can use to learn more about it. I still don't see the benefit of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of that is that your are coding to a contract rather than an specific type. Where the created interface is a the contract that you establish.

For instance this example that is from Interface C# by jeremy clarks

When you have a repository for people with a method that create people and return an array of people using instance of a class person like this

```
Class PeopleRepository
{
   public Person[] GetPeople()
   {...}
}
```

if you create an specific type you do this

```
PeopleRepository pr = new PeopleRepository()
Person[] people = pr.GetPeople()
foreach(var in people)
         //Do something
```

if in your repository class you change the implementation of GetPeople to return a List instead and Array then your code above wont work. However if you use interfaces it will work for instance

```
IEnumerable people;
people = = pr.GetPeople()
foreach(var in people)
             //Do something
```

Like amit said the code will be easier to refactor and easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting the wrong answer is because setting width or height of a square object sets both the width and the height of the square.

so when you set

```
newRectangle.Width = 4
```

then you have a 4x4 square and then you set

```
newRectangle.Height = 5
```

you have a 5x5 square
giving you an area of 25.

A working example of why you would set a class to it's base class is if you removed this method

```
   public static int CalculateArea(Square s)
    {
        return s.Height * s.Height;
    }
```

you would still be able to calculate the area of a square

Comment: @gorilla thanks. I know what I am getting the wrong answer my question is about why is better create objects using its base type as a its type instead the type that I want to be using in my specific code.